# How downgrade a version of PHP in OpenSuse?

Tags: php, linux, downgrade

I hope someone will help me here. 
I need to downgrade a version of PHP 5.6 to 5.4 in OpenSuse 13.2, but can not find a detailed guide how to do it. I suppose that need to delete the current version, specify the repository with the old version, install PHP 5.4 out and block this package for updates. But how does it all done, and whether this algorithm is right really?

Comment: Not very familiar with OpenSuse, but I can't help but wonder if there is a different or better way than downgrading. There were not too many changes which would cause 5.4 code to fail on 5.6 except perhaps some deprecated functions finally removed, APC caching replaced by opcache. Do you know the reason for the 5.4 requirement? Perhaps it can be worked around.

Comment: Due to the lack of compatibility of return with some mysql function.

Comment: Interesting. The chief difference (possibly the only difference) between 5.4 & 5.5-5.6 was that the `mysql_*()` API was deprecated and issues an `E_DEPRECATED` notice (which can be suppressed). Exact specifics would help, mainly because 5.4 has just recently gone out of support http://php.net/supported-versions.php